# Fallo en el feed de preguntas por etiqueta

Tags: soporte, bug, estado-completado, etiquetas

desde hace un par de horas no funcionan los feeds de preguntas por etiqueta:

[`java`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[`javascript`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque si vas a preguntas si que salen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El sitio en ingles funciona correctamente.

Usando: Google Chrome `Version 52.0.2743.116 m (64-bit)`

Es solo a mi? O hay algun problema?

Comment: Mismo caso. Lo puedo reproducir

Comment: Comprobado. No funciona. Me imagino que será algo temporal.

Comment: Además, sí obtengo resultados para [`perl`](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl)

Comment: Supongo que [esto está relacionado](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lZ7QB.png) ... Además, preguntas como esta http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/21051/127 no están apareciendo en el home como activas

Comment: Lo mismo usando FF.

Comment: Estamos investigando esto...

Answer (score 1):

Esto [había sido discutido en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31787885#31787885), y se informó [cuando se solucionó](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31789883#31789883).